# VueJS2: Retrieving user value over pages

Tags: php, vuejs2

Here's a page of `index.php`.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    jobtype_select: '',
    jobtype_list: [{
        id_JobType: 'JTY0001',
        name_JobType: 'Survey'
      },
      {
        id_JobType: 'JTY0002',
        name_JobType: 'Research'
      },
      {
        id_JobType: 'JTY0003',
        name_JobType: 'Maintenance'
      }
    ],

    joblevel_select: '', //{ id_JobLevel: 'JLE0001', nama_JobLevel: 'Low'},
    joblevel_list: [{
        id_JobLevel: 'JLE0001',
        nama_JobLevel: 'Low'
      },
      {
        id_JobLevel: 'JLE0002',
        nama_JobLevel: 'High'
      }
    ]
  }

});
```

```html
<div id='app'>
  <form method="post" action="action.php">
    <div class="">
      <label for="jobtype_id" class="control-label required"><strong>Choose Job Type</strong></label>
      <div v-for='jobtype in jobtype_list'>
        <label class="">
                            <input  type="radio" 
                                    id= 'jobtype_id'
                                    v-model= 'jobtype_select'
                                    :value="jobtype"
                                    name='jobtype_select' 
                                    > 
                            {{jobtype.name_JobType}}
                        </label>
      </div>
      <p> This is : {{jobtype_select}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
      <label for="joblevel_id" class="control-label required"><strong>Job level</strong></label>

      <!-- This is using Vue.JS 2 -->
      <div v-for='level in joblevel_list' class="input-group">
        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input  type="radio" 
                                    id= 'joblevel_id' 
                                    class="form-check-input"
                                    v-model='joblevel_select'
                                    :value="level"
                                    name='joblevel_select'
                                    > 
                            {{level.nama_JobLevel}}
                        </label>
      </div>
      <p> This is : {{joblevel_select}}</p>

    </div>

    <div>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qs/6.5.2/qs.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to get the user input from there to `action.php` so this is what I do

```
<?php
    session_start();
    var_dump($_POST);
    /** Returns
    array(2) { 
      ["jobtype_select"]=> string(15) "[object Object]"
      ["joblevel_select"]=> string(15) "[object Object]" 
    }
    */

    $data = json_decode($_POST['jobtype_select']);
    var_dump($data);
    // Returns NULL

    echo $data; //BLANK PAGE
    echo json_decode($data); //BLANK PAGE

    echo $data->jobtype_select->name_JobType;
    /* Well it's already null
    Notice: Trying to get property 'jobtype_select' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\myPlainDashboard\action.php on line 29
    Notice: Trying to get property 'name_JobType' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\myPlainDashboard\action.php on line 29
    */

    $data2 = $_POST['jobtype_select'];
    var_dump($data2);
    // Returns string(15) "[object Object]"
?>
```

**What I wanted to do:** Retrieve user input values from `index.php` and able to use it in `action.php`. It has to be both the id, and the name. How will this be achieved? If you need more info, please ask me in comment.

Comment: This output you've posted is from `var_dump($_POST);` , isn't it? P.S: Can you post sample data input?

Comment: Yes it is, and what do you mean by sample data input?

Comment: I meant sample data that you POST. You can't just `echo` JSON data, it's object type. If you have var `$json = json_decode($data)` you could use `echo $json->jobtype_select->name_JobType;` for example. I believe you have to sent your data from JS JSON encoded.

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while, cause I'm not focus, I think I just get what you meant.. Question is updated..